# Why is a class not assignable?

Tags: c++

Why is `func_getter` class provided below is not assignable?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <class T, class ReturnType>
using FuncPtr = ReturnType(T::*)() const;

template <class T, class ReturnType>
class func_getter
{
public:

    using MyFuncPtr = FuncPtr<T, ReturnType>;

    constexpr func_getter(MyFuncPtr p) : m_p(p) {}

    func_getter(const func_getter&) = default;
    func_getter(func_getter&&) = default;
    func_getter& operator = (const func_getter&) = default;
    func_getter& operator = (func_getter&&) = default;

    constexpr ReturnType operator() (const T& val) const
    {
        return (val.*m_p)();
    }

private:

    MyFuncPtr m_p;
};

struct X
{
    int a;
    std::string b;

    int GetA() const
    {
        return a;
    }

    int GetA1() const
    {
        return a;
    }
};

using GetAPtr = FuncPtr<X, int>;

static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<GetAPtr>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<GetAPtr>);
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<GetAPtr>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<GetAPtr>);

inline constexpr auto a_getter = func_getter(&X::GetA);

static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<decltype(a_getter)>);
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<decltype(a_getter)>);
```

all the above `static_asserts` do not fail, but the following fail (at least with MSVC2022):

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<decltype(a_getter)>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<decltype(a_getter)>);
```

why?

Comment: why remove the includes? Everybody who wants to look at the code with a compiler has to add them back

Comment: you cannot assign to `a_getter` when it is `constexpr`

Comment: `constexpr int x = 42; x= 0;` same thing

Comment: `a_getter` has `const` qualifier, you'll need to use `std::remove_const_t<decltype(a_getter)>` to get to the core type

Comment: or `std::decay_t` depending on what you want

Comment: Note there are some `const` objects that *are* copy_assignable, like `const std::tuple<int&>` (or anything else with a `auto operator=(const class_type&) const;`): https://godbolt.org/z/qfbef6zGb

Comment: Why make the example code so complicated? Whenever your example code has a template, it's a good idea to see if the template is necessary. I moved the definition of `X` up, removed the `template` line from `func_getter`, then replaced `T` with `X` and `ReturnType` with `int`. Tested and got the same error. Simpler. Then I looked at the `operator()`, saw it was unused, and eliminated it. Which also allowed eliminating the data member. Which led to a chain of simplifications ending with `class func_getter {};` `inline constexpr auto a_getter = func_getter();` and `static_assert`s. Much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(a_getter)` is not just not assignable because `a_getter` is `constexpr`, hence `const`.

If you want to infer the type without const qualifier from `a_getter` you can use `std::remove_const_t` or `std::decay_t` (https://godbolt.org/z/7qvhaqxeW).

Comment: @JaMiT oh right, I confused the types. Dont have time to improve it now, I tried to make it at least less wrong